# Spacing issue. Replace tables with divs

Tags: html, html-table

There is a huge gap above this table, and I cannot understand why.

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```css
.table-size-guide td {
  border: 1.5px solid #ced9e0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #ced9e0;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.sizing-table {
  color: #fd8014;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-size-guide" style="width: 100%;" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-top: 8px;  padding-right: 40px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 12px; background-color: #ededed;">
        <span style="color: #ff8f07;"><strong>Waist Size</strong></span>
      </td>
      <td style="padding-top: 8px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 12px; background-color: #ededed;">
        <span style="color: #ff8f07;"><strong>To fit Height</strong></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">26in</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">128cm</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">27in</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">134cm</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">28in</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">137cm</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">29in</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">140cm</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">30in</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">146cm</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">31in</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">152cm</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">32in</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">152cm</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">33in</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">152cm</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">34in</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">152cm</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">35in</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">158cm</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">36in</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">158cm</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">38in</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">158cm</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">40in</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">158cm</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">42in</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">158cm</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">44in</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">158cm</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">46in</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">158cm</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">48in</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">158cm</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">50in</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="sizing-table">158cm</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Ideally, I would like to convert the table to divs but have been unable to find a solution as there are quite a few rows and columns. Any advice?

Comment: please post your css also? update with full code or add with in a fiddle

Comment: As you can see in the snippet in your question that the problem is not with this code. My guess is that the problem with the other code (the element which wrap the table. Do you have a public URL of your project? Or can you create a snippet which reproduce the problem?

Comment: Since you're displaying tabular data I don't think it should be converted to divs at all. As for debugging, I'd recommend commenting out/removing the inline CSS, and see if the problem persists. If it goes away, put the CSS back gradually and that way you can track down where your layout goes renegade.

Comment: I have edited to show CSS. Unfortunately, it is a development site so cannot show it live.

Comment: I will give the debugging by remove inline css a try and let you know how it goes - thanks.

Comment: Problem is not in the table, we need the code above